# Singularity of a complex function in $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f $ be holomorphic in the punctured disk $D_1 (0)\setminus \{0\} $.

1) Given that there is a constant $A$ such that, when $z $ is near to $0$, we have $|f (z)|\le A|z|^{-\frac 1 2}$, what types of singularity can have $f $ in $0?$

2) Given that there is a constant $A$ such that, when $z $ is near to $0$, we have $|f' (z)|\le A|z|^{-\frac 3 2}$, what types of singularity can have $f $ in $0?$

Point 1 is easy: under these premises $|zf(z)|\le A|z|^{\frac 1 2}$, so $zf(z)\to0$ as $z\to 0$. This means that $f$ cannot have a pole of any order in $0$, nor an essential singularity. For point 2 I reasoned like this: $|z^2f'(z)|\le A|z|^{\frac 1 2}$, so $z^2f'(z)\to0$ as $z\to 0$. This means that $f'$ can have a removable singularity, or a simple pole in $0$; however the solution of the exercise says that $f$ can only have a removable singularity. It seems quite evident to me that if $f'$ has a pole in $0$, $f$ cannot have a removable singularity in $0$; so how do I exclude that our function has a simple pole in $0$? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to think about $f$, not just $f'$, here. Suppose that $f$ has a pole of order $\geq 1$ at $0$. Then write $f$ locally as $z^{-m} h(z)$ where $h$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0$ and $h(0) \neq 0$ and $m$ is the order of the pole of $f$ at $0$.

Then by the product rule, near $0$ $$f'(z) = -mz^{-(m+1)}h(z) + z^{-m}h'(z),$$ hence $f'(z)$ has a pole of order $m + 1$ at $0$. Your argument shows that $f'(z)$ has a pole of order at most $1$ at $0$. We conclude that $f$ has a pole of order at most $0$ at $0$, hence $f$ has a removable singlularity at $0$ and the case that $f'$ has a pole of order $1$ at $0$ is actually impossible.

Comment: Thank you, so basically one could also say that $f'$ can't have a simple pole in $0$ because the function $\frac 1 z$ has not a holomorphic primitive, right?

Comment: @Dorian Yes, that's the main idea!